# wifi keeps on and off all all the time

Tags: wireless

I have a Acer travilmate. After installing Ubuntu and connecting to a wireless network, my Wifi  keeps turning on and off all the time, I hardly could do anything

This is really annoying because it stop me doing anything , I hardly load a video or game.

Is there any way to fix this and just let the wifi work As is required ?

Result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` :

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0110]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4352] (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0110]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945BG Network Connection [8086:1005]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
0a:09.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller [104c:8039]
```

Result of `lsmod` :

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             31981  0 
ppdev                  17391  0 
bnep                   18893  2 
rfcomm                 53664  16 
btusb                  23443  0 
bluetooth             323622  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
coretemp               13195  0 
joydev                 17097  0 
acer_wmi               31735  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 acer_wmi
snd_hda_codec_si3054    12864  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    45592  1 
gspca_vc032x           31199  0 
gspca_main             27772  1 gspca_vc032x
videodev              107508  2 gspca_vc032x,gspca_main
snd_hda_intel          42658  3 
snd_hda_codec         164003  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_intel
arc4                   12536  2 
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                89488  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
iwl3945                63619  0 
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
microcode              18830  0 
iwlegacy               87971  1 iwl3945
i915                  589697  3 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
mac80211              513247  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25094  1 snd_seq_midi
psmouse                90642  0 
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
pcmcia                 51368  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              401436  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
drm_kms_helper         46867  1 i915
serio_raw              13189  0 
snd_timer              24447  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
drm                   242354  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd                    60790  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
yenta_socket           40193  0 
soundcore              12600  1 snd
pcmcia_rsrc            18319  1 yenta_socket
tifm_7xx1              13163  0 
pcmcia_core            22328  3 pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
lpc_ich                16864  0 
tifm_core              15040  1 tifm_7xx1
wmi                    18590  1 acer_wmi
video                  18777  2 i915,acer_wmi
mac_hid                13037  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40795  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12492  0 
usbhid                 47361  0 
hid                    87370  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sky2                   52910  0
```

Result of `iwconfig` :

```
iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Etisalat"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C8:D1:5E:5B:CB:2C   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Result of `ifconfig -a` :

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:36:9b:da:24  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:116454 (116.4 KB)  TX bytes:116454 (116.4 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:de:46:aa:77  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:deff:fe46:aa77/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:892621 (892.6 KB)  TX bytes:478504 (478.5 KB)
```

Result of `sudo iwlist scan` :

```
sudo iwlist scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: C8:D1:5E:5B:CB:2C
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Etisalat"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000fee9c2e01
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000845746973616C6174
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C0103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706454720010D10
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Result of `cat/etc/resolv.conf` :

```
cat/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTENnameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: What are the applications you installed for Wifi network ?

Comment: non i didn't install any application

Comment: Try with installing WICD network manager. `sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk wicd wicd-daemon wicd-curses wicd-cli`. Let us know the outcome.

Comment: could not connect to wicd's D-Bus interface. check the wicd log for error messages. it didn't work >.<

Comment: So try with installing wifi device drivers `sudo apt-get install collectd-core collectd-dev collectd-dbg collectd-utils`

Comment: still don't work properly

Comment: Are there any other solutions ?? :(

Answer (score 2):

**Different Problems can cause this**

Application errors, Driver problems, Hardware problems including overheat, Network Interferences, Network registration, Channel you selected etc.

First get rid of Interfering devices like mobile phones etc.

Go to `Network Connections` > `Wireless` > `Edit` and set it as automatically connect.

Check with power off the device.

```
sudo iwconfig [INTERFAE]wlan0 power off
```

`[INTERFAE]` may be `wlan0` or `eth0` (or 1,2,3, etc)

*If not resolved.:*

**Install device drivers for wifi**

```
sudo apt-get install collectd-core collectd-dev collectd-dbg collectd-utils
```

**And change the applications**

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk wicd wicd-daemon wicd-curses wicd-cli
```

With Wicd, change the Channel to 6.

---

If not resolved yet Edit the question with including the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`, `lsmod`, `iwconfig`, `ifconfig -a`, `sudo iwlist scan`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Someone with expert knowledge may help.

Comment: i did i hope some one can help me