# Wireless won't connect in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, internet

I have now worked a while with Ubuntu but still not really into it.

However everything worked fine after the Installation, now about after a weak I'm getting issues with my wifi. In the beginning all worked as it should.

But then it got slower and slower and even completely stopped sometimes, so that I had to reconnect to my network. But since yesterday I'm not able to connect to my network at all.

It just loads and loads and after a few minutes it says `disconnected`. Now I tried to delete it and reconnect to it and when I enter the passcode for my network and I click ok it tries to connect, but after a minute or two the box appears again but with my passcode already entered.

I am sure the passcode is right

So my question: How can I get my wifi back to work?

Comment: Try and see with [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/393754/224082) answer.

Answer (score -1):

delete the connection 
and run following command in terminal

sudo service networking restart

Comment: When I run those mentioned cmmands all but my backgroundpicture disappears and I have to reboot my laptop