# Very slow Wifi with DWA-140 REV:B2 Wifi Dongle

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10

My wifi is extremely slow when I am using my Wifi USB adapter DWA-140 in Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

In Windows I can easily get speeds of 3-3.5 MB/s. In Ubuntu it has its peaks around 400 kb/s.

I have already searched but not found any solution yet. Since it is working on Windows I would love to get it working on Linux too instead of buying a new wifi adapter.

My output of `lsmod | grep ^rt` :

```
rt5572sta             798486  0 
rt2800usb              27005  0 
rt2x00usb              20713  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              79963  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              55238  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
```

If I blacklist rt2x,rt28 the adapter wont work anymore. It was a solution on some other question but did not help.

I also ran `sudo iwconfig wlan2 power off` . It did not help either.

How to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/393754/224082). You can install the drivers containing packages and applications for wifi. If driver applications are already installed, try with purge them and reinstall.

Comment: I tried it. But still no difference.